# How to make height of all rows in <thead> & <tbody> same?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with first 4 columns fixed and rest all scrolling.
For this code is as follows:

```
   <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="outerTable">
        <thead valign="top">
            <tr>
                <td>S.No.</td>
                <td>Agent </br>name</br>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Port / Offices</td>
                <td>Address</td>
            </tr>
           <?php            
                while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($agent_res))
                {   
                  ?>
                    <tr valign="middle">
                        <td><?php echo $row1['agent_no'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row1['agent_name'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row1['port'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row1['address'] ?></td>
                    </tr>
                 <?php
                }

        ?>   
         </thead>
         <tbody valign="top">
            <tr>
                <td>Tel</td>
                <td>Fax</td>
                <td>Contact</td>
                <td>Email Address</td>
                <td>Website Address</td>
                <td>Strength Ocean Air BB</td>
                <td>Communication / Response Time</td>
                <td>Rate Competitiveness</td>
                <td>Expertise in Execution</td>
                <td>Nominations</td>
                <td>Financial Dealing</td>
                <td>Country Network</td>
                <td>Network Assoc.</td>
                <td>Agency Agreement</td>
                <td>Average Score</td>
                <td>Origin Charges</td>
                <td>Destn Charges</td>
            </tr>
               <?php
                mysql_data_seek($agent_res, 0);

                        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($agent_res))
                        {   
                            ?>  
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['tel'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['fax'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['contact'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['email_id'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['website_address'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['strength_ocean_air_bb'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['communication_or_responce_time'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['rate_competitiveness'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['expertise_in_execution'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['nominations'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['financial_dealing'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['country_network'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['network_assoc'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['agency_agreement'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['avg_score'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['origin_charges'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row2['destination_charges'] ?></td>
                            </tr>     
                            <?php
                        }
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

CSS:

```
table#outerTable thead, table#outerTable tbody {
            display:inline-block;
        }

        table#outerTable tbody {
            width: 500px;
            overflow-x: scroll;
        }
```

i am getting output as follows:
[image]

Rows are not displaying in the same line in `<thead>` and `<tbody>`.
I want height of rows in both `<thead>` and `<tbody>` same.
So can anyone help me out in this regard.
Thanks in advance.
Waiting for your replies.

Comment: Might sound silly but have you tried setting the height in your css?

Comment: @Anand Jaju use css instead of mark up in html, this will also fix you're problem

Comment: @DeclanGreally: data is coming from database, we cannot predict the height of data. so how can we use height property?

Comment: setting a min-height to a <tr> might work for that. or expand the columns.

Comment: Well, the tables aren't in line for that very reason. If you look, you can see that Website Address is double lined, increasing the height of that box, as is the website below it.

Comment: I'd recommend either setting a standard height for all boxes (it'd look at lot better that way) and/or increasing column width.

Comment: All of those properties you're using (valign, cellspacing, etc.) are deprecated.